# org-publish: Wrong number of arguments: plist-get

Tags: org-mode, debugging, org-publish

I tried to configure `org-publish` with some html variables, but I'm getting this error `let: Wrong number of arguments: plist-get, 3`. I've `debug-on-error` enabled but doesn't show up the minibuffer.

This is my config `.el` file.

```lisp
(require 'ox-publish)
(require 'ox-rss)


;; Initial configuration
(setq project-source "~/org/blog/"
      project-dest   "~/org/public/"
      website-url    "blog.me")


(setq blog-head
  "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/site.css\" type=\"text/css\">")


(setq blog-preamble
  "<div class=\"nav\"><ul>
  <li><a href=\"/\">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"/blog/index.html\">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"http://github.com/NicolasPetton\">GitHub</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"http://twitter.com/NicolasPetton\">Twitter</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"/contact.html\">Contact</a></li>
  </ul></div>")


(setq org-publish-project-alist
      `(("org"
         :base-directory "~/org/blog/"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "~/org/public/"
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
         :section-numbers nil
         :with-toc nil
         :html-head-extra ,blog-head
         :html-preamble ,blog-preamble)
        
        ("posts"
         :base-directory "~/org/blog/posts/"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "~/org/public/posts/"
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
         :section-numbers nil
         :with-toc nil
         :html-preamble ,blog-preamble)

        ("images"
         :base-directory "~/org/blog/images/"
         :base-extension "jpg\\|gif\\|png"
         :publishing-directory "~/org/public/images/"
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)

        ("js"
         :base-directory "~/org/blog/js/"
         :base-extension "js"
         :publishing-directory "~/org/public/js/"
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)

        ("css"
         :base-directory "~/org/blog/css/"
         :base-extension "css"
         :publishing-directory "~/org/public/css/"
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)

        ("rss"
         :base-directory "~/org/blog/"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "~/org/public/"
         :publishing-function (org-rss-publish-to-rss)
         :html-link-home "http://blog.me"
         :html-link-use-abs-url t)

        ("blog" :components ("org" "posts" "images" "js" "css" "rss"))))
```

backtrace

```
Resetting org-publish-cache
Loading /Users/elia/.emacs.d/.local/cache/org-timestamps/org.cache...done
Publishing file /Users/elia/org/blog/blog-setup.org using ‘org-html-publish-to-html’
Note: sgml-basic-offset, tab-width adjusted to 2
Saving file /Users/elia/org/public/blog-setup.html...
Wrote /Users/elia/org/public/blog-setup.html
Resetting org-publish-cache
Loading /Users/elia/.emacs.d/.local/cache/org-timestamps/posts.cache...done
Resetting org-publish-cache
Loading /Users/elia/.emacs.d/.local/cache/org-timestamps/images.cache...done
Resetting org-publish-cache
Loading /Users/elia/.emacs.d/.local/cache/org-timestamps/js.cache...done
Resetting org-publish-cache
Loading /Users/elia/.emacs.d/.local/cache/org-timestamps/css.cache...done
Skipping unmodified file /Users/elia/org/blog/css/styles.css
Resetting org-publish-cache
Loading /Users/elia/.emacs.d/.local/cache/org-timestamps/rss.cache...done
Publishing file /Users/elia/org/blog/blog-setup.org using ‘org-rss-publish-to-rss’
Saving file /Users/elia/org/blog/blog-setup.org...
Wrote /Users/elia/org/blog/blog-setup.org
let: Wrong number of arguments: plist-get, 3
```

so yes is `ox-rss` the problem. I'm using [this ox-rss.el](https://github.com/emacsmirror/ox-rss/blob/master/ox-rss.el) locally

Comment: Show a backtrace, with the complete error msg and some of the call stack. You don't show any code that contains `let` of `plist-get`.

Comment: The `rss` publishing function looks suspect: the parentheses are probably wrong. Whether that's what's behind the error is unknown: you need to give us a backtrace as @Drew requested. Making sure that `debug-on-error` is `t` and running `org-publish` should be enough for that. If you don't get a backtrace, try `M-x top-level` before checking the variable and re-running `org-publish` - or start with a fresh session of Emacs.

Comment: That's not a backtrace: it's just the output. Moreover, there is no indication that I can see that `ox-rss` *is* the problem from the output you show. Did you have to get rid of the parentheses around `org-rss-publish-to-rss`? As it stands, the question is incomplete and possibly misleading. Please fix it.

Comment: What @NickD said. Please post the backtrace you get from `debug-on-error`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing `org-contrib` via elpa.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21945)

Comment: Installing `org-contrib` instead of using `ox-rss.el` file taken from the source, solved the problem. So I would consider it a valid answer to my issue

Comment: It looks like `ox-rss` is no longer part of `org-contrib` on nongnu elpa as of `org-contrib` version 0.4. This solution no longer works.